# How to: Jade HTML content after child element

Tags: pug

I have an `h1` with a content of "World" and with a `span` with content "Hello" as its immediate child. How do I put the `h1`'s content ("World") after the span's content ("Hello")?

Here's the code (Jade HTML):

```
h1
  span Hello
  World
```

Output:
Hello

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jade provides three common ways of getting plain text. You can read the [documentation here](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/).

So by piping at the start of the text, it behaves as normal text and not a HTML tag.

```
h1
span Hello
| World
```

You can also add it inline.It will be in a single line which makes the jade code more readable.

```
h1 #[span Hello] World
```

Or add a custom class to span

```
h1 #[span.custom-classname Hello] World
```